# Change the logical volume

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, lvm, snapshot

I am quite new this **snapshot** process.

Let, I have three **logical volumes** as A, B, C.

I worked on logical volume C. But accidentally when I restart the system, it goes to the snapshot A. How can I change the snapshot to C?

I referred this link for it: http://www.tutonics.com/2012/12/lvm-guide-part-2-snapshots.html

Also I tried it by changing the fstab file but it didn't worked. Is this possible to change the snapshot? If yes, how?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Could you please post the output of three commands: `sudo pvs`, `sudo vgs`, `sudo lvs`